# How can an HTTP 403 be returned from an apache web server input filter?

Tags: c, apache, apache2, apache2.4, apache2-module

I have written an apache 2.x module that attempts to scan request bodies, and conditionally return 403 Forbidden if certain patterns match.

My first attempt used `ap_hook_handler` to intercept the request, scan it and then returned `DECLINED` to the real handler could take over (or 403 if conditions were met).

Problem with that approach is when I read the POST body of the request (using `ap_get_client_block` and friends), it apparently consumed body so that if the request was subsequently handled by mod_proxy, the body was gone.

I think the right way to scan the body would be to use an input filter, except an input filter can only return `APR_SUCCESS` or fail.  Any return codes other than APR_SUCCESS get translated into HTTP `400 Bad Request`.

I think maybe I can store a flag in the request notes if the input filter wants to fail the request, but I'm not sure which later hook to get that.

Answer (score 1):

turned out to be pretty easy - just drop an error bucket into the brigade:

```
apr_bucket_brigade *brigade = apr_brigade_create(f->r->pool, f->r->connection->bucket_alloc);
apr_bucket *bucket = ap_bucket_error_create(403, NULL, f->r->pool,
        f->r->connection->bucket_alloc);
APR_BRIGADE_INSERT_TAIL(brigade, bucket);
bucket = apr_bucket_eos_create(f->r->connection->bucket_alloc);
APR_BRIGADE_INSERT_TAIL(brigade, bucket);
ap_pass_brigade(f->next, brigade);
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution, but the server always gives 400, not the custom code what I set up in ap_bucket_error_create(). Do you have any idea, how can I debug?